# Installing Audacity in Parrot OS : Step by Step

Tags: audacity, parrot-os

I am new in the Parrot OS and downloading apps in it is entirely different from windows.Can anyone give me a step-by-step tutorial on how to install Audicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parrot OS is based on Debian, i.e. similar to Ubuntu and Mint
so "apt" should work...

The possibly simplest way is to use this
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/audacity

Note: make sure to avoid v 2.3.0 - which apparently does not work on Linux:en. There is a 2.3.2 available...

i.e. to **install:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/audacity
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audacity audacity-data
```

Then press the super / left windows key and type "audacity", then pick up the icon with your mouse pointer and place it in the launcher.

**Removal**:

```
sudo apt-get purge audacity audacity-data 
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/audacity
```

Remove icon; right click and select "unlock from launcher".

*The full process above is untested, please tell if details does not work*